# libgdx resizable / moveable window with scrollpane

Tags: resize, libgdx, scrollpane

If I explicitly position / size a scrollPane (ick!) I can use the title bar of its window to drag the window, if I make the scrollPane smaller still then I can also then resize the window.

However, as the window is resizeable I need to set the scrollPane fill its parent (presumably) - this then means when I start to drag the window with the title bar it starts to move but then stops and the scrollPane starts scrolling instead.

Despite padding on the window (which looks visually correct) there is still an issue with the title bar and moving the window.

Resizing is worse because at first it tries to dropdown a selector inside the scrollPane then it starts resizing the table and then it starts scrolling the scrollPane!

The widgets are laid out thus:

```
window    
    scrollPane
           table
```

I have tried padding / setting sizes on different widgets but nothing seems to work when the window is resizable...

to recap I'm looking to make a resizeable re-positionable window with a scrollPane inside it that changes size when the window does but doesn't effect resizing or repositioning of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I should have added the scrollPane with *add* and not *addActor*, jeese I wish there were better info in the javadocs!

NOPE! thats not it either, the pane is stuck to the right size of the window

v.frustrating

finally!

```
    sPane.setFillParent(true);
    win.add(sPane).fill().expand();
```

still no idea from the API doc's or Wiki if this is how you're *supposed* to use it...